# Unable to update ubuntu via terminal through a proxy server

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-gnome

I am currently a newbie in ubuntu. I have ubuntu 14.04 and want to update it via terminal.
I use proxy server (which requires authentication ie username and password)to access internet. I can easily surf internet but when it comes to Ubuntu software centre or an update through terminal, i am unable to do it.Terminal always gives 'error 407 proxy authentication required' and then fails. Please help me with this.

Comment: what command do you use for using terminal with proxy???

Comment: i did this which i found from a link in askubuntu.com         "
i edited apt.conf by using

sudo vi /etc/apt/apt.conf
There are already 4 lines of code starting with Acquire key word, edit it like this:

Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyhost:port/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://username:password@proxyhost:port/";
Acquire::ftp::Proxy "ftp://username:password@proxyhost:port/";
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyhost:port/";"